# Azure DevOps how to run exe database migration

Tags: powershell, devops, exe

We have fluent migrator wrapped in a .net core console app which we added extra functionally to. We had this working on octopus deploy but trying to get it to work in azure DevOps release pipeline is proving very difficult.

We have a **Deploy.ps1** powershell file with a single command in it which is as follows

```
& .\Migrations.exe -connectionStrings "Server=<server>,1433;Initial Catalog=MigrationTest-Dev;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=<name>;<password>;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

This runs fine locally and as I say on our octopus box.

How would I be able to run this in devops release pipeline, I can only think its permission related maybe!?

The below is the current Powershell task in the release pipeline

[image]

If anyone could provide some help it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Where is the YAML file ? you have to add the trusted host ,The next step in pipeline is the configuration of the PowerShell task for running a command or script file in a target machine

Comment: See the answer below. I maybe went down the wrong path of trying to use powershell to open database firewall, but easy to do with the confusing results searching for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working after finding this post https://rajbos.github.io/blog/2019/08/17/AzureDevOps-Run-NET-Core.

The solution was this PowerShell task, which this inline script. Note that because this is a .net core console app I could run dotnet on the .dll and don't have to use the .exe

```
cd "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_SqlMigrationsTest/Migrations-Wip/Migrations"

dotnet Migrations.dll -connectionStrings "Server=<server>;Initial Catalog=MigrationTest-Dev;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=<name>;Password=<password>;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

[image]

The yaml looked like this if I clicked the **View YAML** link.

```
steps:
- powershell: |
   cd "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_SqlMigrationsTest/Migrations-Wip/Migrations"
   
   dotnet Migrations.dll -connectionStrings "Server=<server>;Initial Catalog=MigrationTest-Dev;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=<name>;Password=<password>;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
  displayName: 'Run Migration'
```

So this did run but then I had an issue with the azure database firewall rules, I spent a day looking into powershell script to connect to the database and add a new firewall rule. The IP constantly changes in devOps(which is expected). I never got the azure firewall scripts working, it was all around Get-AzureRmSqlServerFirewallRule or the other Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServerFirewallRule which was a very painful approach that never worked.

I later stumbled upon the solution where the azure database has firewall settings(which I knew I could add manually). There is a toggle to **Allow Azure services resources to access this server**. Putting this to **Yes** made it all work, finally.

[image]